# Wildcard search for LINQ to SQL

Tags: search, linq-to-sql, wildcard

I want to do a wildcard search using LINQ to SQL.
using Contains, StartsWith, EndsWith **only**.
(not "SqlMethods.Like" method)

the wild cards operate with two type of jokers:

? - any character  (one and only one)
* - any characters (zero or more)

Is there a way to do this?

Regards

Comment: LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework??

Comment: LINQ to SQL, thanks

Comment: What is wrong with SqlMethods.Like? Contains, StartsWith and EndsWith all end up generating a SQL like statement.

Comment: @sgmoore Since the database isn't mentioned, one possible issue is the database provider may not support `SqlMethods`.

Answer (score 0):

No it isn't possible. If you have both `?` and `*` in your matching expression, there is no way to convert the `?`.

Also, to convert `?` by itself would require using `Length`.